# How to implement light color change of a traffic light with pure css?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build a traffic light model in Html and css . I wonder if there is anyway to do the light color changing with pure css and without using javascript.
I have tried using animation but couldn't get my desired result. I want the light color every 5 seconds.

here is my html code:

```css
html,
body {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  width: 60%;
  height: 100%;
  background: pink;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#panel {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  /*position: relative;*/
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  /*top: -70px;*/
  width: 30%;
  height: 60%;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.light {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: lightgrey;
  border-radius: 100%;
  animation-name: colorChange;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

#red {
  animation-name: redColor;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

#yellow {
  animation-name: yellowColor;
}

#green {
  animation-name: greenColor;
}

#bar {
  width: 10%;
  height: 30%;
  background: black;
}


/*@keyframes redColor{
     from{background-color: red}
     to{background-color: grey}
    }*/


/*@keyframes yellowColor{
     from{background-color: yellow}
     to{background-color: grey}
    }
    
    @keyframes greenColor{
     from{background-color: green}
     to{background-color: grey}
    }*/
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="panel">
    <div class="light" id="red"></div>
    <div class="light" id="yellow"></div>
    <div class="light" id="green"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="bar"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can play around with the % of the animations. So if you want orange to be shorter you can increase/decrease the percentages.
Not the most responsive way to do it but it answers your question at least :P

```css
html,
body {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  width: 60%;
  height: 100%;
  background: pink;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#panel {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  /*position: relative;*/
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  /*top: -70px;*/
  width: 30%;
  height: 60%;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.light {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: lightgrey;
  border-radius: 100%;
  animation-name: colorChange;
  animation-duration: 15s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

#red {
  animation-name: redColor;
}

#yellow {
  animation-name: yellowColor;
}

#green {
  animation-name: greenColor;
}

#bar {
  width: 10%;
  height: 30%;
  background: black;
}


@keyframes greenColor{
     0%{background-color: green}
     33%{background-color: green}
      34%{background-color: grey}
      100%{background-color: grey}
    }


@keyframes yellowColor{
      0%{background-color: grey}
     33%{background-color: grey}
      34%{background-color: yellow}
      66%{background-color: yellow}
      67%{background-color: grey}
      100%{background-color: grey}
}
    
    @keyframes redColor{
      0%{background-color: grey}
      66%{background-color: grey}
      67%{background-color: red}
      100%{background-color: red}
    }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="panel">
    <div class="light" id="red"></div>
    <div class="light" id="yellow"></div>
    <div class="light" id="green"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="bar"></div>
</div>
```